# Why does the name of the UK not change to UQ during the reign of a Queen?

Tags: terminology, demonyms

The term *queendom* implies the territory possessed by the crown and denotes the country or state ruled by a queen. *[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/queenhood#etymonline_v_54991)* says

> **Queendom** is from c. 1600 as "country ruled by a queen," 1650s as "state or rank of being a queen."

If most other terms and national bodies change from using K to Q, such as QC/KC, [Queen's Printer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King%27s_Printer)/King's Printer, etc. Why not the name of the country itself?

Comment: You mean, UQ as in The United [Queendom](https://www.etymonline.com/word/queenhood#:~:text=%22state%20or%20rank%20of%20being,rank%20of%20being%20a%20queen.%22)? Sure…

Comment: There are two votes for closing the question because it lacks research, so I've added some.

Comment: Is this a language question or a politics question? I can think of a lot of practical reasons why the name wouldn't change but they are outside the scope of English Language and Usage; as are questions such as "do other countries change their names in a similar situation?" You could ask "can 'kingdom' refer to a realm ruled by a queen?" but that's rather trivial.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has England, Scotland, or the United Kingdom ever been referred to as a queendom?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/594867/has-england-scotland-or-the-united-kingdom-ever-been-referred-to-as-a-queendom)

Comment: I would expect a Queendom to be ruled by a line of queens, i.e. the ruler would be female unless no female ruler was available.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The question is good and fine but do you think it is closable as a duplicate?

Comment: @Mitch  If I vote to close it as a duplicate, it looks like my vote will be the only one, and the question gets closed for *please include the research* without a link to the older question. This is the result of users being able to close a question with only three votes. Oh, the answer to your question is "yes" but it was too late before and it's too late now.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Not having the duplicate link is a poor but unintended side effect of the machinery for closing here. (but I don't think '3' as a limit is what does that).

Comment: Also (I didn't notice before that) this has been closed and reopened once already, -and- the voting is large and mixed. If anyone searches for 'queendom' on the web, Urban Dictionary and other actual dictionaries mention the term well before there's a link to stack overflow, but if 'stackoverflow' is added the 'dupe' is the first one. Alhabet's answer is fine so I'm not VTC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[As MW explains,](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kingdom) "kingdom" means:

> a politically organized community or major territorial unit having a monarchical form of government headed by a king **or queen**

[If Ngram Viewer is to be believed,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kingdom%2Cqueendom&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) the word "queendom" is, by comparison, almost never used.